# FolderBrowserDialog and "." in Pathname

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem by using the fb.SelectedPath function of the FolderBrowserDialog.
Everything is fine, as long as the absolute path does not contain any ".".

For example:

```
try
{
    if (arg == 1)
        fb_dialog.SelectedPath = Path.GetFullPath(tb_path.Text);
    else
        fb_dialog.SelectedPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
}
catch { fb_dialog.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer; }
```

If System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location does not contain any ".", it navigates the user into that folder. Let's say the path is like that: "C:\Prog"
But if it returns a path with a "." in it, like "C:\Prog.Test", it won't work. It opens the dialog, returns no errors but stucks at the "root" of the filebroser (if specified, otherwise its "Desktop").

Any Ideas how to solve that issue? Because it's quite annoying.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE:** Solved by keyboardP in this post: [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239271/1478230)

Comment: Perhaps there is a system issue here because I can use the following path without error:  `R:\Documents\Sheets\my.folder\another.dot.folder`

Comment: @terrybozzio You'd have to do something like:  `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Path.GetDirectoryName` doesn't know whether or not you've provided a folder with a dot in it or a file with an extension (e.g. is file.txt a text file or a folder?).

If you know it's a directory, a workaround could be to do something like this.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\\")
```

This ensures that `GetDirectoryName` is aware it's looking at a directory and not at a file because of the trailing `\`.

**Updated answer based on comments**

This issue seems `FolderBrowserDialog` specific (the above info should work in other cases). I was able to reproduce your issue and I managed to find a relatively hacky workaround but it seems like it's a bug with the `FolderBrowserDialog` so this should suffice.

If you set the `RootFolder` property to one that contains the path you're inputting, it works. For example, if you set the `RootFolder` to `SpecialFolders.MyDocuments` and your input is `C:\...\My Documents\test.dot.folder`, it should work. Therefore, the workaround iterates through the `SpecialFolders` enum and sets the first match.

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
   fbd.SelectedPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

   //find closest SpecialFolder that matches the input (can be expanded to not be case-sensitive)
   foreach (var sf in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)))
   {
       string spath = Environment.GetFolderPath((Environment.SpecialFolder)sf);
       if (fbd.SelectedPath.Contains(spath))
       {
           fbd.RootFolder = (Environment.SpecialFolder)sf;
           break;
       }
   }

   fbd.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `GetDirectoryName()` makes no assumptions regarding input.

Comment: It does not affect the situation. Because programmatically it adds a subfolder at the end. It works, if the path does not contain a dot, but it doesnt, if there is one.

Tested with another folder structure. As long as there is no dot inside, it works and shows the working folder as i want it to.

Comment: I'll provide a screenshot, when i'm at home. just to show the problem, if that's okay.

Comment: @Thyrador - Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. I've updated the answer to show an example of what I mean. As far as I can tell those are the values you want? Screenshot is fine, just reply to me after you've posted it so I know to check back :)

Comment: And again. I can work with that folder, that isn't the problem. It just DON'T show it in the dialog window. it stucks at its root and does NOT navigate into the folder that i set earlier. Outside the dialog window everything runs fine and i still can work with that structure, even if there's a dot inside. It only affect the dialog browser window itself

Comment: @Thyrador you are using folder browser to investigate files?

Comment: @terrybozzio

no, just to set a directory to start with. if there is no specific folder in it, it starts at "MYCOMPUTER". It just starts always in "MYCOMPUTER", if the path contains at least one dot.

Comment: @Thyrador - I figured out what you mean. It seems like a bug but I've updated the answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: @keyboardP Well, I tested what you suggested and it works! Thank you for that. Everything runs fine now  :)

Comment: Mhh, played around with that code and it seems that it cannot provide the full browser structure (where you can select the root, different disks, etc) when using a path where it navigates you into a spcial folder, right?

Let's say, it guides me into "APPDATA\App", i cannot select any disks (like C:\) from file browser dialog.
This can't be avoided, right?

Comment: @Thyrador - The FolderBrowserDialog control isn't very versatile unfortunately. As far as I can tell, once you set the root folder you're stuck within that directory. The choice seems to be to either use your original code (which does keep the actual value of `SelectedPath` as the correct one, it just doesn't start in that position) or limit the user's directory choice. Alternatively, you could maybe use a [third party implementation](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) of the dialog box instead which seems more customizable.